# CRUD in ASP.NET Core 6.0: Keyword not supported: '"server'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In steps for a [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operation for ASP.NET Core 6.0, I am getting an error in Update-Database command ....Keyword not supported: '"server'.

How can I fix it? It is in this: Keyword not supported: '"server'.

I have checked the SQL server connection string and the database details.

Connection string in the appsettings file:

```
"DefaultConnection": "server=servername; database=EmployeeDB; User Id=sa; Password=xxx; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

I have installed the packages *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer* and *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools*.

Comment: What's your connection string in the appsettings file ?

Comment: "DefaultConnection": "server=servername; database=EmployeeDB; User Id=sa; Password=xxx; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"

Comment: Do you have `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` package installed ? And what the packages do you installed ?  Do you have another .json file where the connection string was messed up ?

Comment: Yes, i have installed below packages  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Comment: Could you share your Program.cs  code about `builder.Services.AddDbContext...` and appsetings code ? Besides, what's your SQL server  database like ?

Comment: Do you try `"DefaultConnection": "Server=servername; database=EmployeeDB; User Id=sa; Password=xxx; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" `

Answer (score 0):

The connection string was modified as below and the issue was resolved:

> "ConnectionString": "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=Databasename;Integrated Security=True;User Id=sa;Password=xxx;TrustServerCertificate=True;"

Comment: What is the gist of the change? Why does it work? Or why didn't the original work? What was wrong with it?

Answer (score -2):

The error message you're encountering, "Keyword not supported: 'server'", typically indicates an issue with your connection string in ASP.NET Core 6.0 when using Entity Framework Core for database operations. This issue is often related to a malformed connection string or a configuration problem. Here are the steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

1. Check Your Connection String:
   Ensure that your connection string in the `appsettings.json` (or `appsettings.Development.json` for development) file is correctly formatted. It should look something like this:

   ```json
   "ConnectionStrings": {
       "DefaultConnection": "Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDatabaseName;User Id=YourUserId;Password=YourPassword;"
   }
   ```

   Make sure there are no extra quotes or syntax errors in the connection string. Replace "YourServerName," "YourDatabaseName," "YourUserId," and "YourPassword" with your actual database server details.
2. Verify DbContext Configuration:
   In your ASP.NET Core project, make sure that your `DbContext` class is properly configured with the connection string. It should be something like this in your `Startup.cs`:

   ```cs
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
   ```

   Ensure that you are using `UseSqlServer` for SQL Server databases.
3. Entity Framework Core Migrations:
   If you are using Entity Framework Core for database migrations, make sure you have run the following commands in the Package Manager Console or terminal to create and apply migrations:

   ```bash
   dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
   dotnet ef database update
   ```

   Replace "InitialCreate" with an appropriate migration name.
4. Check for Special Characters:
   Ensure that you don't have any special characters or escape sequences in your connection string that could be causing issues.
5. Test Connection String:
   You can also test your connection string outside of your application to see if it's working correctly. You can use tools like SQL Server Management Studio or SQL Server Data Tools to test the connection.
6. Double-check Database Server:
   Verify that your SQL Server instance is running and accessible from your application. Also, check if the server name is correct and that it allows connections from your application's server.
7. Review Entity Framework Core Version:
   Ensure that you are using the correct version of Entity Framework Core that is compatible with ASP.NET Core 6.0.
8. Clear and Rebuild:
   Sometimes, cached configurations can cause issues. Try clearing the bin and obj folders of your project, and then rebuild and run the application again.

After going through these steps, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue with your connection string and the "Keyword not supported: 'server'" error. If the problem persists, please provide more details about your connection string and configuration so that I can assist you further.

Comment: Hello I have follow the above guideline but there is still same issue , i have recreated all

Comment: @Prafull The answer looks AI-generated. I wouldn't take it seriously